# error occured when uploading a file with IIS

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I have developed a web application, which runs good when executed from Visual studio.

The theme of the application is to get the content in the excel file and display it.

We had a file upload control in our application, to get the excel file.

It works like charm when executed from the VS and i could see the desired result, but it is giving error when browsed through IIS.

Code is developed in Framework 4.0

The excel file is not uploading, and throws an error that error occured while reading the file.

Here is my code ..

Can you detect what goes wrong when browsed through IIS ?

```
 DataSet dsRates = new Schemas.Rates();
        DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
        dtDBTable = dsRates.Tables[0];
        DataTable dtColumnNameNotFound = new DataTable();

        FileStream stream;
        string changed = string.Empty;
        string FilePath = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (ValidateUserInputs())
            {
                DataSet dsExcel = new DataSet();
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
                try
                {
                    if (fupExtract.HasFile == true)
                    {
                        FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/" + fupExtract.PostedFile.FileName);

                        fupExtract.SaveAs(FilePath);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fupExtract = ((FileUpload)Session["FileUploadCtrl"]);
                        FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/" + fupExtract.PostedFile.FileName);
                        fupExtract.SaveAs(FilePath);

                    }


                    //Read the Excel Data in to Datatable
                    string _ConnectionString = string.Empty;
                    string _Extension = Path.GetExtension(FilePath);
                    if (_Extension.Equals(".xls", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        _ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;" + (char)34;

                    }
                    //Use ACE OleDb     
                    else if (_Extension.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {

                        _ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;" + (char)34;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = fupExtract.FileName + "is not a supported format, only '.xls|.xlsx' files are supported";

                        return;
                    }
                    int i = 0;

                    con = new OleDbConnection(_ConnectionString);
                    con.ResetState();
                    con.Open();

                    DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    foreach (DataRow Sheet in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        OleDbDataAdapter daExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + Sheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim() + "]", con);

                        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
                        daExcel.Fill(dtData);
                        var filteredRows = dtData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row.ItemArray.Any(field => !(field is System.DBNull)));
                        if (filteredRows.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            dsExcel.Tables.Add(dtData);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Error occured while reading the file";

                    con.Close();
                }
        finally
                {
                    if (File.Exists(FilePath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(FilePath);
                    }


                }
```

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer to my question.

It's that I haven't installed Office 64-bit and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. The one I'm using is 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use Interop in order to read your excel document

```
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        var xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("yourFile.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        var xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        Console.Write(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1","A1").Value2.ToString());

        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: can you tell me what exactly is the problem